# Do my relational algebra operations produce the desired results?

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra

I have these tables:

```
        Sailors          

sid  sname   rating  age
---  ------  ------  ---
22   dustin  7       45 
31   john    8       55 
58   ben     10      35
```

```
         Boats        

bid  bname      color
---  ---------  -----
101  interlake  blue 
102  interlake  red  
103  clipper    green
104  clipper    red
```

```
       Reserves

sid  bid  date
---  ---  ----------
22   104  8/10/2014
22   103  7/05/2014
58   103  8/11/2014
31   102  8/11/2014
```

I am trying to find *sailors*, *sname* and *rating*, who have reserved both a *red* and a *green* *boat*, and I need to write that in relational algebra notation.

I tried this:

[image]

Text version, for copying/referencing purposes:

```
R1 := Boats ⋈ Services
R2 := σcolor='Red'(R1)
R3 := σcolor='Green'(R1)
R4 := R2 ∩ R3
R5 := R4 ⋈ Sailors
R6 := πsname,rating(R5)
```

I was told it was wrong, but not given an explanation as to why. Can someone explain to me what the problem is?

This line was marked as wrong:

```
 R4 := R2 ∩ R3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed the error:

```
    R4 := R2 ∩ R3
```

If we try to get the intermediate results of your solution, we get:

**R1:**

```
bid  bname      color       sid  date
---  ---------  -----       ---  ----------
102  interlake  red         31   8/11/2014
103  clipper    green       22   7/05/2014
103  clipper    green       58   8/11/2014
104  clipper    red         22   8/10/2014
```

and then:

**R2:** (only the 'red')

```
bid  bname      color       sid  date
---  ---------  -----       ---  ----------
102  interlake  red         31   8/11/2014
104  clipper    red         22   8/10/2014
```

**R3:** (only the 'green')

```
bid  bname      color       sid  date
---  ---------  -----       ---  ----------
103  clipper    green       22   7/05/2014
103  clipper    green       58   8/11/2014
```

`R4` will be an empty relation because nothing can be both red and green. Of course that is not what the exercise asks for.

**R4:**

```
bid  bname      color       sid  date
---  ---------  -----       ---  ----------
```

---

What you need to do is to get `R2'` and `R3'`, the projections of `R2` and `R3` respectively, with only the attribute `sid`. Then take their intersection for `R4`:

```
    R1  := ...
    R2  := ...
    R3  := ...
    R2' := πsid(R2)
    R3' := πsid(R3)
    R4  := R2' ∩ R3'
    R5  := ...
    R6  := ...
```